# concourse resource - task output not available to put

Tags: fedora-25, concourse

How do I `put` the `output` of a `task` into a resource?

```
  - name: build-pkg-rpm
    public: true
    plan:
    - aggregate:
      - get: oregano-test-fedora
      - get: git-clone-resource
        trigger: true
        passed: [compile, build-docker-image-fedora]

    - task: create-rpm
      image: oregano-test-fedora
      config:
        platform: linux
        inputs:
        - name: git-clone-resource
        outputs:
        - name: srpm
          path: ../srpm
        run:
          path: .concourse/fedora/buildrpm.sh
          dir: git-clone-resource

    - put: srpm
      resource: copr-resource
      params:
        rpmbuild_dir: "srpm/rpmbuild/SRPMS"
        chroots: ["mageia-6-x86_64", "mageia-couldron-x86_64", "fedora-rawhide-x86_64", "fedora-25-x86_64"]
        enable_net: false
        max_n_bytes: 250000000
        project_id: 825
        regex: ".*oregano-.*\\.src\\.rpm$"
```

`buildrpm.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
set -x

pwd 2>&1
RPMBUILD_DIR="$(pwd)/../srpm/rpmbuild/"
mkdir -p ${RPMBUILD_DIR}/{SOURCES,BUILD,RPMS,SRPMS,SPECS}

# fill all vars of the spec.in
./waf configure rpmspec
cp -v build/rpmspec/oregano.spec ${RPMBUILD_DIR}/SPECS/

# generate the distributable tar
./waf dist
cp -v oregano*.tar.xz ${RPMBUILD_DIR}/SOURCES/

cd ${RPMBUILD_DIR}
rpmbuild \
--define "_topdir %(pwd)" \
--define "_builddir %{_topdir}/BUILD" \
--define "_rpmdir %{_topdir}/RPMS" \
--define "_srcrpmdir %{_topdir}/SRPMS" \
--define "_specdir %{_topdir}/SPECS" \
--define "_sourcedir  %{_topdir}/SOURCES" \
-ba SPECS/oregano.spec && echo "RPM was built"
pwd 2>&1
```

According to

https://github.com/starkandwayne/concourse-tutorial/tree/master/12_publishing_outputs

this should work, yet the directory in the put step is empty.

The documentation https://concourse-ci.org/put-step.html seems to not cover this topic very much.

I see that the files are writte properly:

```
Wrote: /tmp/build/be0f50d1/srpm/rpmbuild/SRPMS/oregano-0.84.3-1.fc25.src.rpm Wrote: /tmp/build/be0f50d1/srpm/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/oregano-0.84.3-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm Wrote: /tmp/build/be0f50d1/srpm/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/oregano-debuginfo-0.84.3-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm Executing(%clean): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.6mO3iF
+ umask 022
+ cd /tmp/build/be0f50d1/srpm/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd oregano
+ rm -rf /tmp/build/be0f50d1/srpm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/oregano-0.84.3-1.fc25.x86_64
+ exit 0
+ echo 'RPM was built' RPM was built RPM was built
+ pwd /tmp/build/be0f50d1/srpm/rpmbuild
```

But then when it comes to `put` the task's `output`, it does not find any files:

```
base dir: "/tmp/build/put/srpm/rpmbuild/SRPMS"
error: Could not find any matches with that regex
caused by: WalkDir entry is useless
caused by: IO error for operation on /tmp/build/put/srpm/rpmbuild/SRPMS: No such file or directory (os error 2)
caused by: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

When I hijack into the containers:

```
1: build #136, step: create-rpm, type: task
2: build #136, step: srpm, type: put
```

---

choose a container: 1

```
[root@f004c6a0-adee-4735-792f-8e237f645751 be0f50d1]# ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  44 May 31 11:43 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  24 May 31 11:43 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 598 May 31 11:43 git-clone-resource
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  16 May 31 11:43 srpm
[root@f004c6a0-adee-4735-792f-8e237f645751 be0f50d1]# ls -al srpm/rpmbuild/
BUILD/     BUILDROOT/ RPMS/      SOURCES/   SPECS/     SRPMS/     
[root@f004c6a0-adee-4735-792f-8e237f645751 be0f50d1]# ls -al srpm/rpmbuild/
BUILD/     BUILDROOT/ RPMS/      SOURCES/   SPECS/     SRPMS/     
[root@f004c6a0-adee-4735-792f-8e237f645751 be0f50d1]# ls -al srpm/rpmbuild/SRPMS/
total 1232
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root      58 May 31 11:43 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root      70 May 31 11:43 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1260666 May 31 11:43 oregano-0.84.3-1.fc25.src.rpm
```

---

choose a container: 2

```
/tmp/build/put # ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            82 May 31 11:43 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             6 May 31 11:43 ..
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           414 May 31 11:31 git-clone-resource
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           130 May 23 07:25 oregano-test-fedora
drwxr-xr-x    1 42949672 42949672         0 May 31 11:43 srpm
/tmp/build/put # #ls -al srpm/
/tmp/build/put # #ls -al srpm/
/tmp/build/put # #ls -al ../srpm
/tmp/build/put # ls -al ../srpm
ls: ../srpm: No such file or directory
/tmp/build/put # ls -al srpm
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    1 42949672 42949672         0 May 31 11:43 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            82 May 31 11:43 ..
```

**So why is the file structure nor `oregano-*.src.rpm` available in the put step?**

The full concourse YAML is avail here, though not necessary as far as I can tell https://github.com/drahnr/oregano/blob/master/.concourse.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was this:

```
- task: create-rpm
  image: oregano-test-fedora
  config:
    platform: linux
    inputs:
    - name: git-clone-resource
    outputs:
    - name: srpm
      path: ../srpm
```

`path: ../srpm` placed the outputs outside the volume and as such the content was lost. Note that `dir` does not do anything regarding the `inputs` and `outputs` but just changes the workdir for the execution of the script!

The default would have sufficed which would have equaled to `path: srpm` (or `path: ""`)

This works:

```
- task: create-rpm
  image: oregano-test-fedora
  config:
    platform: linux
    inputs:
    - name: git-clone-resource
    outputs:
    - name: srpm
```